# How to find latest category change for product using excel function

Tags: excel

I have below scenarios with million rows where I have to fill data based on another table. Can someone please help on this

Table 1:

```
Date       Category Product   Change?

1/1/2010​   Cat 1   Prod 1  
12/2/2019​  Cat 2   Prod 1  
1/1/2020​   Cat 3   Prod 3  
3/2/1989​   Cat 4   Prod 4  
5/2/1990​   Cat 5   Prod 4  
2/2/2020​   Cat 6   Prod 2
```

Table 2:

```
Product    Category  Expected Category

Prod 1               Cat 2
Prod 2               Cat 6
Prod 3               Cat 3
Prod 4               Cat 5
```

Problem 1:
I have to fill the latest category in Table 2 based on the latest date available in Table 1. Expected Category (answer) is given in Table 2 last column

Problem 2:
True/False to be filled in Table1 "Change?" column based on if there is any category change for the product

Comment: Can you please provide the expected result? Why are there 2 columns for `Category` in table 2?

Comment: Sort the data by date descending in table 1 then use INDEX/MATCH

Comment: @dwirony -- Table 2 last column name is "Expected Category" which is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to sort the table.

You mentioned the data is in Tables, so I use that with structured references.  You could certainly switch to regular addressing if that is an issue.

If you have O365 with the `FILTER` and `SORT` functions, you can use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Product]=[@Product]),1,-1),1,2)
```

- `FILTER` returns a table which contains only the designated Product
- `SORT` then sorts that table `descending` so that the newest is in the first row.
- `INDEX` returns the contents of the first row, second column which will be the relevant Category.

[image]

If you do not have those functions, you can use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(Table1[Product]=[@Product])*Table1[Date],1)=Table1[Date])*([@Product]=Table1[Product])),Table1[Category])
```

Comment: Great and Awesome. This actually solved my problem.. Thanks a lot.. I don't have those structured references or those functions. I used your lookup formula and it perfectly solved my problem 1.

Comment: @user2847638 Glad to help. You should have structured references as they are part of the **Table** feature.  Once you get used to them, they make formulas more understandable, so it might be worthwhile, when you have time, to take a look at that.  With regard to the `Changed` column, would that include a `Y` for the most recent change also?  If so @NareshBhople COUNTIF is the way to go.  If not, we can create another formula.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if table is sorted on dates in ascending order as shown in your table. Then you will get the latest category.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($C$2:$C$7=F5),$B$2:$B$7)
```

True/False to be filled in Table1 "Change?" column based on if there is any category change for the product ... This can be done by countifs. If there is change the product will appear more than once.

So `D7 = IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,C7)>1,"True","False")`

[image]

Comment: For my 1st problem I used Ron Rosenfeld's formula and for problem 2 I used your formula. Thanks a lot for helping me out on this. You guys are awesome

Comment: Please accept / tick Ron Rosenfeld's answer and close the question